# Friendly_id with two parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, friendly-id

I wonder if there's an easy way to use friendly_id and have two parameters instead of one, like this?

www.example.com/dateTitle/

date and title are two separate fields in my db.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know this question was made 2 years ago, but if it can help for future readers, friendlyId gem now integrates the 'candidates' funcionality that can help with this.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  def slug_candidates
   [
    [:created_at, :Title],
   ]
  end
end
```

More info in the gem [repo](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Answer (score 9):

There sure is!

Just define a method on the model that formats the string before it gets slugged

Refer to this example: https://gist.github.com/2650300

Comment: This helped me out. Thanks!